# navigation to previous page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my application I inserted a button to go back to the previous page, doing it manually:

```
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage(obj1, obj2, obj3, objIspi, ImgByte1, ImgByte2, ImgByte3, FrasiChanged))
```

In this way it goes back to the previous page, in the MainPage, but there the application has to reload some methods, making everything slower.
I tried to use the method

```
await Navigation.PopAsync ();
```

On android, however, it throws me an exception because it is not supported. Is there an alternative to return the application to the previously opened app from the navigation stack?

Comment: When you use PushModalAsync, you need to use the matching PopModalAsync method.  PopAsync goes with PushAsync.

Comment: how you navigate **back** depends on how you navigated **forward**.  If you used PushAsync, then use PopAsync.  If you used PushModalAsync, use PopModalAsync.  If you used something else, then you need to explain what you did.

Comment: @Stefano As jason said that the `ModalPage` instance must invoke the `PopModalAsync` method to return to the original page.

Comment: I solved it following your reasoning.  thanks a lot to everyone